# Determining the similarity between two documents

Tags: java, clustering

I've made some code that reads in text files (which hold quite large vectors of word frequencies), which in turn stores each index of a vector within an `ArrayList` for their specified team (i.e. `Arsenal` vector to the `Arsenal` `ArrayList`, `Chelsea` vector the `Chelsea` `ArrayList`, etc.). It then uses a cosine similarity function to determine similarity between the two documents and writes it to a file.

What I would like is to make the code that reads in the text files (and storing them in their corresponding `ArrayList` more efficient), rather than me change the parameters of the while loop each time i need to use it.

```
public static Double cosineSimilarity(ArrayList<Integer> vectorOne, ArrayList<Integer> vectorTwo) {

    Double dotProduct = 0.0;
    Double normVecA = 0.0;
    Double normVecB = 0.0;
    for(int i = 0; i < vectorOne.size(); i++) {
        dotProduct += vectorOne.get(i) * vectorTwo.get(i);
        normVecA += Math.pow(vectorOne.get(i), 2);
        normVecB += Math.pow(vectorTwo.get(i), 2);
    }

    return dotProduct / (Math.sqrt(normVecA) * Math.sqrt(normVecB));

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    ArrayList<Integer> arsenal = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> chelsea = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> liverpool = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> manchesterCity = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> manchesterUnited = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> tottenham = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    Scanner textFile = new Scanner(new File("Enter textfile  here"));

    while (textFile.hasNext()) {
        arsenal.add(textFile.nextInt());
   }

    Double output = cosineSimilarity(arsenal, chelsea);

    File fileName;
    FileWriter fw;

    // Create a new textfile for listOfWords
    fileName = new File("arsenalCosineSimilarities.txt");
    fw = new FileWriter(fileName, true);

    fw.write(String.valueOf("Chelsea: " + output + "\n"));

    fw.close();
}
```

Comment: In the current example code, `chelsea` never gets any values. Do you have an example text file and can made this code runnable and testable so that it's possible to try it out by ourselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For flexibility, your `cosineSimilarity()` method should taken in `List<Integer>` arguments, instead of `ArrayList<Integer>` arguments.  This method doesn't care how the list is stored, only that it is a list which implements `.size()` and `.get(i)` methods.

For efficiency you should used `double` variables, not `Double` objects in the method:

```
public static double cosineSimilarity(List<Integer> vectorOne,
                                      List<Integer> vectorTwo)
    double dotProduct = 0.0;
    double normVecA = 0.0;
    double normVecB = 0.0;
```

---

When you open a `Scanner`, you should `.close()` it, to prevent resource leaks.  The "try-with-resources" construct will automatically close resources that it opens.  So instead of:

```
Scanner textFile = new Scanner(new File("Enter textfile  here"));
```

use

```
try(Scanner textFile = new Scanner(new File("Enter textfile  here")) {
    // use textFile inside this block.
}
// textFile is automatically closed when the block is exited.
```

Ditto with `FileWriter`.  Use "try-with-resources" to automatically close the writer.

```
try(FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileName, true)) {
    fw.write( ... );
}
// fw has been automatically closed at this point.
```

---

If you are using `.nextInt()`, you should loop on `.hasNextInt()`, not `.hasNext()`.

```
while(textFile.hasNextInt()) { 
     arsenal.add(textFile.nextInt());
}
```

---

It sounds like you want a `Map<String,List<Integer>>` to store an `ArrayList` for each team.

```
List<String> team_names = List.of("Arsenal", "Chelsea", "Liverpool",
        "ManchesterCity", "ManchesterUnited", "Tottenham");

Map<String,List<Integer>> stats = new HashMap<>();

// Read in all team stats from (for example) "<TeamName>_stats.txt" files

for(String team_name : team_names) {
   List<Integer> team_stats = new ArrayList<>();
   try (Scanner textFile = new Scanner(new File(team+"_stats.txt"))) {
      while(textFile.hasNextInt()) {
          team_stats.add(textFile.nextInt());
      }
   }
   stats.put(team_name, team_stats);
}
```

Then you can use `stats.get(team_name)` to get each team's stats for comparison / analysis

```
for(String team1_name : team_names) {
   List<Integer> team1_stats = stats.get(team1_name);

   for(String team2_name: team_names) {
      // Skip comparing a team against itself
      if (team1_name.equals(team2_name))
          continue;

      List<Integer> team2_stats = stats.get(team2_name);

      double output = cosineSimilarity(team1_stats, team2_stats);

      // ... display "output", or write to file, or ...
   }
}
```

Depending on how you want your output written (one file for all comparisons, or one file per team for a comparison with all other teams, you'll want to open the `FileWriter` before the outer loop, or before the inner loop.

Comment: True that it's better to use `List` instead of `ArrayList`. Important note though is that a `LinkedList` would be much slower here, as the `.get(index)` method is O(n) instead of O(1) as in ArrayList.

Comment: @SimonForsberg Yes, but at least it would work, instead of being a compiler error.  Of course, the efficiency issue can be fixed by using an iterator, instead of `.get(i)`.

Comment: @AJNeufeld Yup, totally agreed. In fact, I would definitely recommend using an `Iterator` here.